# Want extjs grid to ignore whitespace

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Is it possible to make a grid in extjs ignore whitespace at the front?

We are getting some data back and sometimes there is a **\t** or a **" "** at the front.

eg:

```
    "name": "\tAIR Client",

    "name": " ISTA_DAT_0024_3.44.30",
```

Sure it is possible to write code to process the data and remove the empty spaces, but if extjs grids has a sort option to trim the string, that would make my day easier :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an [Ext.String.trim(string)](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.String-method-trim) method.

This will remove whitespace at the beginning and end of the passed string, but not any whitespace in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution would be removing the white spaces on the model level, but you can also use a [`renderer`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer) function on your columns

```
renderer: function(value){
    return value && Ext.String.trim(value);
}
```